# If I have a 28mm f/1.8 lens (on a crop body), do I still need the 50mm f/1.4?

Tags: lens, focal-length, normal

I have the Canon 60D and a Canon 400D (my original camera). I have two lenses a Sigma 50mm 1.4 HSM and a Canon 28mm 1.8 USM. Both lenses are incredible performers. I've noticed the bokeh I receive on the 28mm 1.8 is incomparable to the amazing bokeh and tight DOF of the 50mm 1.4. However, being a person that likes to be close to my subjects, I see my photos are composed of 80% from the 28mm and just a few shots with the 50mm.

My question is: the 50mm seems like a great lens on a full frame camera, but the 28mm seems to fit the part for a 1.6 crop APC size sensor. Do I really need the Sigma 50mm 1.4? And consequently the extra 400D body as well? Or should I sell them for the extra cash before they lower even more in price?

Comment: This is really subjective. Obviously some people need a 50mm F/1.4, otherwise it would not sell. You have to determine if you will use it, which sounds like you wont much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a 1.6× crop-factor body, the 28mm is a "[normal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/what-focal-length-gives-a-normal-field-of-view-on-aps-c-cameras)" lens. As you note, that's roughly the same as a 50mm lens on a full-frame body — so [50mm was the classic normal focal length](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/why-is-the-50mm-prime-lens-the-most-standard). On your camera, the decreased field of view due to the crop means that it acts as something different.

However, that "something different" doesn't mean it's useless. In fact, this short telephoto range is a classic for portrait photography — the 85mm lenses on 35mm film or full-frame DSLRs. So, it certainly has both a use and a purpose — but, whether that's a *need* is up to you. If you find you're never using it, that's probably a sign. Before I'd sell, though, I'd try leaving it on my camera for a few days or weeks, trying to work with the lens and getting to know what it can do for you. That will help you decide if it's worth leaving a spot for it in your camera bag.

Answer (score 7):

You will get much better subject/background separation with the 50 f/1.4, mainly on account of the longer focal length. I personally like the short telephoto angle of view 50mm gives you on APS-c.

But if you don't like composing shots with the angle of view the fifty gives you, and you rarely use it then it probably makes sense to sell it. I don;t know how to answer your question any better than that.