# Is there an EF version of the Canon EF-S 60mm macro?

Tags: lens, full-frame, cropped-sensor, canon-rp

I take a lot of photos of faces. For the last 12 years or so, I've been using a Canon EF-S 60mm macro lens on an EOS 7D. I just upgraded to a Canon RP full-frame. With an adapter, I can mount the EF-S on the RP and it takes photos, but it's only using part of the sensor, so the images come out 10MP instead of the camera's 26MP. Really, it's good enough, but a shame not to use the whole sensor!

I thought I'd just find an EF 60mm macro for full-frame, but I can't find one. Does it not exist? What are my options now?

Thanks!
/SD

Comment: What's your particular need for 60mm on full frame? If you want the same angle of view as the 60mm gave you on the 7D, you'll want a 100mm lens... [which does exist](https://www.canon.co.uk/lenses/ef-100mm-f-2-8-macro-usm-lens/specification.html) (there's an L version as well if you want to spend more money)

Comment: If you can no longer make the pictures you want to make, is it really an upgrade? Would it be simpler to just use the old camera and lens?

Comment: Excellent. Phil: it looks like I have some gaps in my understanding. Ages ago when I was even more a beginner, a consensus was a 60mm fixed macro, Canon's, was superb for faces, and I've used it since, always of course on a non-full-frame Canon camera, but a Canon film camera before that. I'm used to it and happy with it. But if the focal length must change with a full frame, I guess I need to learn more. Any links or specific advice? Bob: that makes sense. My 7D's electronics seem to have gremlins, and I assumed a new camera wouldn't get me in trouble. But now I need to get this figured out.

Comment: @user533604 - [What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-crop-factor-and-how-does-it-relate-to-focal-length) is our canonical question on the subject.

Comment: @user533604 It is ok to replace a crop sensor camera with another crop sensor camera. It is a perfectly fine format.

Answer (score 4):

The full frame EF equivalent of the EF-S 60mm f/2.8 Macro USM is the EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM (the earlier non-L version). On an APS-C camera like your 7D, the angle of view you get with a 60mm lens when focused at infinity is similar to the angle of view you get with a 96mm lens on a FF camera.

Both lenses have 12 elements in 8 groups.

Both lenses have a Maximum Magnification (MM) of 1.00X, or a reproduction ratio of 1:1.

On an APS-C body the EF-S 60mm Macro has Angles of view of 25° (diagonal), 21° (horizontal), and 14° (vertical).

On a FF body the EF 100mm Macro has Angles of View of 24° (diagonal), 20° (horizontal), and 14° (vertical).

Unlike the EF-S 60mm f/2.8 Macro, which has been discontinued, the EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM is still officially sold new by Canon dealers, though most seem to have it on backorder at the moment (a lot of things are currently on back order from all major camera manufacturers due to the current global supply crunch of semi-conductor chips). It's not on the list of EF lenses Canon recently announced had either been discontinued or would be discontinued by the end of 2021.

For the RF mount there's also the new RF 100mm f/2.8 L Macro IS USM, which is the "L-Series" counterpart to the EF 100mm f/2.8 L IS USM Macro. The EF "L" is currently available at most dealers. The newly announced RF "L" has not yet begun shipping but, as of today, June 10, 2021, can be pre-ordered from official Canon dealers.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.Question, possibly naive: Since the EF-S 60mm on an APS-C has almost identical angles of view as the EF 100mm on a FF body, does that mean, that if using the EF-S 60mm/APS-C I stand 42 inches from a subject and her face about fills the frame in portrait orientation, that using the EF 100mm/FF I would stand the same 42 inches from her to fill the frame with her face, and the two images would look similar, since I'm standing the same distance from her? Not as though one were up closer with a lower focal length lens and the other were taken farther away with a more telephoto lens?

Comment: Yes, from the same distance the framing would be the same with a 60mm lens on Canon APS-C and a 100mm lens on FF. Keep in mind that angles of view are calculated for infinity (far) focus. Different lenses can change fields of view differently as they're focused closer than infinity. Even two differently designed 100mm lenses used on the same FF camera that would have the same field of view when focused on infinity can have different angles of view when focused more closely. However, in the case of two Macro lenses, I'd be surprised if there were much difference between them.

Comment: As to the difference in perspective between different focal lengths, **there isn't one**. [Perspective is determined strictly by distance](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76321/15871), not by focal length. The reason we think a wide angle lens distorts faces is because we usually move closer to frame a face when using a wide angle lens, but it's the shorter distance, not the focal length, that causes perspective distortion.