# Do I need 50mm lens If I have 24-105 lens for canon 6d?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, canon-6d

Do I need 50mm lens If I have ef 24-105mm f/4l is usm lens for canon 6d?
What should be my next lens? I mostly interested in landscapes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I really need a fast 50mm lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14313/do-i-really-need-a-fast-50mm-lens) and [Why is the 50mm prime lens the most standard?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/why-is-the-50mm-prime-lens-the-most-standard), also take a look at the 50mm Tag: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/50mm

Comment: If you have a 6D and a 24-105mm lens, and have no idea what lens to buy next, I would advise buying a book, as well as practicing much more in the field. No equipment is going to teach you what you need to learn next. Once you have some experience under your belt, you will know what lens you need next.

Comment: I'll at least point out that if you can afford a 6D with a 24-105, you can probably afford to spend the $100 on a 50 1.8 and play around with it to great effect. Dang if you don't like it, sell it used for at least half that and you're only out $50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are mostly interested in landscapes, spend your money on a **good tripod**, if you don't already have one. Then spend your time shooting, traveling, etc. If when you find yourself limited by your lens, then you will know what to buy.

Shoot, critique, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a lens to do something that a 50mm prime lens can do that the EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS can't do then **yes**, you need a 50mm lens.

Until *you* can explain exactly what it is you need the 50mm prime to do that the EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS can't do, **no** you don't yet need a 50mm lens.