# What is the better Nikon primes among 50mm/1.8G, 50mm/1.8D and 35mm/1.8G for my D3200?

Tags: lens, nikon, digital, nikon-d3200

which is a better prime lens for my Nikon D3200? nikor 50mm f 1.8g or nikor 50mm f 1.8D or nikor 35 mm f 1.8G ?? nikor 50mm f 1.8 is much cheaper. Though money is a constraint for me if the other lenses are worth it and will be useful in the future then i am ready to get.

Comment: Also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/nikkor-f-1-8g-35mm-or-50mm

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of `better`. The 35mm is a really good lens for general photography. It is light, quite small and great in low light. It's probably the best lens Nikon make in terms of 'bang for the buck' and lots of people agree that many people with DX cameras should probably have one.

Comment: I am using Nikon D3200 and i am a beginner.nikor 50mm f 1.8D would be fine ?? Is there a vast difference between 1.8G n D(I mean a noticeable diff) ?? or you suggest a 35mm instead of 50mm ?

Comment: After reading some reviews i am really confused. People say 35mm is better. As i am a beginner, i am not able to understand. Can u pls help me

Comment: What is your definition of 'better'?