# Nikon 50mm or 35mm prime for a D5200?

Tags: prime, 35mm, 50mm

I have Nikon d5200 and a kit lens(18-55). I want to buy a prime lens but confused between 50 mm and 35 mm. Need help and suggestion.

Comment: There have been quite a few questions on this topic, for example this one: [Nikkor f/1.8G 35mm or 50mm?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/nikkor-f-1-8g-35mm-or-50mm).  Could you check those answwers and refine your question if you still need help?

Comment: I have voted to close because its unclear why you are "confused" - should I get a cat or a dog? they are different lenses for different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already a 18-55 mm lens.

1) Take some pictures at 50mm. Later take others at 35mm.

What do you like most?

2) Why do you think you need a prime lens in the first place?

Do you want sharper images at 50mm? Or sharper images at 35mm?

3) What are you really photographing? Portraits or buildings?

Answer thoose questions and you will find your answer.

---

Edited:

For the specific issue, bokeh, asumming we have the same aperture: **The longer the focal length, bigger bokeh**.

I bet you have never seeing a fish eye shoot with bokeh. :o)

---

And for the fov. No.

If you shoot a photo at 35 mm, and recompose the main subject with 50 mm you do not get the same perspective. The far objects will look bigger.

It is the effect on a typical horror movie scene where you have a long hall and it looks to get bigger.

Comment: I edited the answer for the "bokeh" part.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly subjective.  the 35mm will give the field of view of a full frame 52.5mm lens (aprox 50), while the 50 will give the field of view of a full frame 75mm lens.

One thing to consider is how you are using each lens.  the 35mm will make distant objects seem smaller, but you will get more of them.  The 50mm will bring distant objects in closer.

The best suggestion I ever received on this was to analyze all of the pictures you have taken so far with your kit lens...look at your favorites... what range did you shoot them at?  all at 55? then get the 50... all around 20-30mm?  go for the 35.

Comment: Actually I want sharpness, bokeh and more fov but not at a same time..in short I want a versatile lens. which is more versatile is a confusion..BTW thanks for the reply..one more question is there if I want a same fov using 50mm, I will step back and get the same fov as a 35mm, will it affect the perspective If I step back?..and in this case which lens give me a better bokeh?

Comment: For bokeh, look at the number of blades for the aperture. Generally, more blades means more "pleasing" bokeh (again, this is highly subjective.) Also, define "versatile". Your kit zoom is, generally, more versatile.

Comment: @saurabh Focal length *never* affects perspective. Stepping back, however, *always* does. When people speak about different focus lengths having different perspective, what they really mean is that the perspective is different because you would have to stand in a different place to make your subject the same size in the frame.

Comment: @jdv More (or rounded) blades can make bokeh look nicer stopped down, but that's hardly the only factor!

Comment: @mattdm, agreed, hence my scare quotes. I was commenting on a single aspect called out by the OP.

Comment: @mattdm, true for composition, but distant objects in the frame will look slightly different between the two.  The 50mm will bring distant things a little closer than the 35mm if the two subjects are framed exactly the same.

Comment: The only way to get the same framing with two different focal lengths is to move closer or farther from the subject, which will indeed affect perspective.