# What is the significance of a 50mm lense?

Tags: lens, 50mm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the 50mm prime lens the most standard?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/why-is-the-50mm-prime-lens-the-most-standard)
>   [Why do people recommend 50mm or other prime lenses as starting lenses for learning photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/why-do-people-recommend-50mm-or-other-prime-lenses-as-starting-lenses-for-learni)

I'm a completely amatuer photography, just trying to figure out why the 50mm lense is important, what it's typically used for (I have been told it's for Portraits, but is there more detail than that?)  How much should I pay for one?  Why should I get one?  I have heard that 50mm lens don't Zoom.  Who makes the best one?  Any details about this would be appreciated!